# PHP: Timezones off by 1 or more days

Tags: php

I have the following ROQL (SQL for Oracle Rightnow) being ran and outputted in PHP.

```
select sum(amount) as c, datecreated from WMP.wmp_obj_statuses where status IN ('New','Pending','Updated') AND datecreated='2017-08-31' LIMIT 25
```

This brings back 3065. All good so far but the datecreated is a day behind.

I also have the following

```
select sum(amount) as amount,datecreated from WMP.wmp_obj_statuses where status IN ('New','Pending','Updated') group by datecreated
```

This brings me back 3065 but the datecreated is `2017-08-30Z`

Try as I might, I can't get this to either bring back the legit date of `2017-08-31` in either the ROQL or PHP

Any ideas? I've tried looking. Doing all manner of strtotime/date functions but now back at a blank canvas

Comment: What is the raw data returned by your queries? What column type is `datecreated`? Is your database running in UTC?

Comment: The `Z` in the datecreated result likely means `Zulu` aka `UTC` is is likely quite different from your local timezone. I'm not familiar with this particular RDBMS, but most tend to define a 'Date' as 'DateTime' with an implicit time part of `00:00:00`.